# Is it possible to notify a service on a different host with puppet?

Tags: service, puppet, host, restart

I have a puppet module for host-1 doing some file exchanges.

Is it possible to inform another puppet agent on host-2 (i.e. with a notify) about a change made on host-1?

And if it is possible, what would be a best practice way to do that?

```puppet
class fileexchangehost1 {
  file { '/var/apache2/htdocs':
    ensure  => directory,
    source  => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/var/apache2/htdocs",
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    recurse => true,
    purge   => true,
    force   => true,
    notify  => Service['restart-Service-on-host-2'],
  }
}
```

Comment: You would be looking at doing this with the Orchestrator and tasks/plans, but that method would also have to be outside of a catalog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many have asked this question and at various times there has been talk of implementing a feature to make it possible. But it's not possible, and not likely to be possible any time soon.

Exported resources was considered an early solution to problems similar to this, although some e.g. [here](https://devblog.timgroup.com/2013/06/14/exported-resources-considered-harmful/) have argued it is not a good solution and I don't see exported resources used often nowadays.

I think, nowadays, the recommended approach would be to keep-it-simple, and use something like [Puppet Bolt](https://puppet.com/products/puppet-bolt) to simply run commands on node A, and then on node B, in order.

If not Puppet Bolt, you could also use MCollective's successor, [Choria](https://choria.io), or even Ansible for this.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet has no direct way of notifying a service on one host from the manifest of another.

That said, could you use [exported resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_exported.html) for this? We use exported resources with Icinga, so one host generates Icinga configuration for itself, then exports it to the Icinga server, which restarts the daemon.

For example, on the client host:

```
@@file { "/etc/icinga2/conf.d/puppet/${::fqdn}.conf":
  ensure  => file,
  [...]
  tag     => "icinga_client_conf",
}
```

And on the master host:

```
File <<| tag == "icinga_client_conf" |>> {
  notify  => Service['icinga2'],
}
```

In your case there doesn't appear to be a resource being exported, but would this give you the tools to build something to do what you need?

Comment: Exporting a resource serves to allow it to be managed on nodes that collect that resource.  That indeed can trigger signals to other resources on the collecting node, but I don't see how that applies to the OP's case, as the key issue to overcome is that the file being managed and the service that should be notified are on *different* nodes.  Are you suggesting that the OP would export some kind of dummy resource serving only to trigger notifications?

Comment: Exactly, John. A dummy resource would do the trick. I'm partly hoping the original poster actually has some hidden configuration which is being 'exported' using some non-Puppet method, and that it'll all fall into place...

Comment: Thanks to both of you, i think i get the idea of how i can use this. I will try and make a Resource with an md5 checksum of the folder. This is going to be my export ressource. I will collect that checksum on the second host and compare it to the old one. If it changed, i'm going to reload the Service.

Comment: @DschungelRatte That sounds like a plan. I'd note that you don't need to compare the checksums - Puppet will spot the difference in file content and kick off the notification of the service without you having to do anything.